# What is the quickest way to kill Hiss Clusters?

Tags: control

I am getting killed a lot and it's usually when I encounter a group of enemies with a healer. The enemy looks like a giant red portal which teleports when you damage it and heals all the enemies around it.

I have tried various tactics and they seem to fail. Such as using Spin to pressure it and Launch to hit it from distance.

However I tend to die before I can actually effect a kill as I'm too open to the additional enemies.

Comment: If you voted to close, can you let me know what details you feel need adding and I can update the question, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hiss Clusters should definitely be a priority in combat, but they shouldn't be your *only* priority. While they can heal their allies, they can't heal themselves. In addition, the healing they output is gradual. This means that you can take your time to whittle them down while managing the rushing enemies. When you can, take the opportunity to Launch some objects at it for damage or take a few potshots with Grip or Pierce, but always keep your field clear so you don't get overwhelmed.

Use Shatter or Spin to manage any enemies that try to rush you. The burst damage from a close-range Shatter should bypass the small gradual healing from the Cluster and kill Agents and Charged outright. Once your immediate vicinity is clear, then you can use the breathing room to put some damage on the Cluster.